# What the best way to retain form values after page reload (click submit)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a filter on the page and I would like to retain the form values after click on button filter.

I'm trying to use cookie (like the code below) but I don know if this way is the best because the cookies are safe on the browser and then it's maybe could make a trouble for my page.

How can I retain form values and then how to populate the form again whit them automatically?

Obs.: Can I get the infos on the URL? The project is using Ruby (rails).

```
$(".searchButton").on("click", function () {
    $.cookie('frachiseesValue', $("#frachisees_filter").val());
    $.cookie('schoolsValue', $("#schools_filter").val());
    $.cookie('challengeValue', $("#post_challenges_filter").val());
    $.cookie('statusValue', $("#statuses_filter").val());
    $.cookie('searchValue', $("#filter_search").val());
    $.cookie('startDateValue', $("#startDate").val());
    $.cookie('endDateValue', $("#endDate").val());
});
```

**UPDATE**
In my case I have 4 selects, 2 input, 1 submit and 1 input search. The select's cookie get select's IDs and no string.

Comment: [sessionStorage or localStorage](http://caniuse.com/#search=webstorage)

Comment: Or a cookie, or a querystring. The 'best' method is a very subjective request

Comment: I got values on cookies but How Can I populate the form with this cookies values? @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: On load: `$("#frachisees_filter").val($.cookie('frachiseesValue'));` etc

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I updated the post, change anything in your answer?

Comment: Nope, not really.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan it's working for `input search` and `input date`, but no for select, maybe because I've got select id and no select  string...

Comment: For a select you need to use the `change` event

Answer (score -1):

You can try:

1. Cookies
2. URL Query String
3. Localstorage
4. IndexedDB

Cookies and Localstorage are well supported and easy to use, where URL Query string will allow you to pass a fullfilled form with just a link if you want to not show them in the url, avoid it